# Node.js - Buffer vs Uint8Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, uint8array

In the documentation [1](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback) of the fs module, we can read (for the writeFile method):

```
const data = new Uint8Array(Buffer.from('Hello Node.js'));
```

In the same documentation [2](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer) it is said:

> With TypedArray now available, the Buffer class implements the
>   Uint8Array API in a manner that is more optimized and suitable for
>   Node.js.

So if the Buffer class implements a Unint8Array, could you enlighten me why we need to convert to an Unint8Array from a Buffer?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts done :)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Uint8Array is a general-purpose byte-array that’s available in both nodejs and browsers. Buffer is a subclass of Uint8Array that’s only available in nodejs (for historical reasons). both are primarily used for manipulating binary (byte) data.

historically, when nodejs first came about, general-purpose Uint8Arrays didn’t exist, so it had to invent its own “Buffer” type for handling binary-data. after general-purpose Uint8Arrays were introduced with es6, nodejs (after version 4.0) decided to migrate Buffer over from a separate data-type -> subclass of Uint8Array (to try and make it more browser-compatible with Uint8Array).

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-relationship-between-a-Buffer-and-an-Uint8Array-in-Node-js